# Does Vue automatically remove all vue/vuex watchers on component destroy?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

If the component subscribes to the `Vuex` events like:
`this.$store.watch` or `this.$store.subscribe`

Is it necessary to remove the watcher during component destroy or `Vue` already takes care of it under the hood?

P.S: Current logic runs on `2.6.10` Vue version.

Comment: Well you can try it out, try to subscribe and see if you still see stuff coming up once the component is destroyed .. FYI store watch within a component is overkill, you can simply use the watch option, watching the state or getter.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, Crisitiano. I agree that subscribe is too much, but still was curios :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Cristiano Soleti I checked if listeners are still being called after component that registered them was destroyed.

...and at least in `2.6.10` version, Vuex watcher are actually not removed automatically when component is destroyed. And thus should be unregistered explicitly by developer in `beforeDestroy` lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 0):

The VueX docs are vague, however it does say "To stop watching, call the returned unwatch function." with no other information, which implies that watchers never get removed any other way: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch

So, you should manually remove a VueX watcher when destroying a component.

Here's an example:

**MyComponent.vue**

```
data: function() {
    return {
        myWatcher: null // Holds the watcher, so we can reference it
    }
},

mounted() {
    // Invoke the watcher
    this.myWatcher = this.$store.watch(state => state.myStoreVariable, (valueNew, valueOld) => {                   
        // Do stuff
        console.log("valueOld: " + valueOld + ", valueNew: " + valueNew)
    })
},

beforeDestroy () {
    this.myWatcher() // Simply calling the watch holder as a function (ie with parentheses) will remove the watcher.
},
```